# sql_who2 gives -2 in the BlkBy column

Tags: sql-server, locking

We had a problem today on our dev server where a process locked one table, stopping all other queries on that table to work. When running `sql_who2` the blkBy columns value was -2, but the -2 was not in the process list.

When running `DBCC INPUTBUFFER (-2)` I got the exception *Invalid SPID -2 specified*.

When running [beta_lockinfo](http://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/beta_lockinfo.html) I see all the tables and indexes it locks, but all other information is null, except that the ownertype was Transaction.

When restarting the webapp(did a change in web.config) the lock dissapered and the same did all the traces of the -2 SPID

My question is why is the SPID a negative value and why can I not get any info about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SPID of -2 represents that your process was blocked by an orphaned distributed transaction.

You can use `KILL 'GUID-OF-THE-UOW'` to terminate orphaned distributed transactions, or any other distributed transaction.  To do this you'll need to get the GUID of the Unit of Work (UOW) from `sys.dm_tran_locks.request_owner_guid`.

```
SELECT
    [tl].[request_owner_guid]
FROM
    sys.dm_tran_locks   tl
WHERE
    [tl].[request_session_id] = -2
```

-2 is just an artificial association.  The session ID of -2 just makes it easier to identify orphaned transactions by querying the session ID column in the dynamic management views.

Comment: Thx! Do you know how if it ispossible to find the source of the distributed transaction? Any inforamtion at all?

Comment: You should be able to open the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator MMC snap-in by typing 'dcomcnfg' at the Start > Run... dialog.

Under the local DTC node, look for transactions that have been marked in-doubt.  Likely this transaction came from a remote server.